# Is tensorflow session in python called as tensorflow.Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying this code at jupyter notebook:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = 2
y = 3
add_op = tf.add(x, y, name='Add')
mul_op = tf.multiply(x, y, name='Multiply')
pow_op = tf.pow(add_op, mul_op, name='Power')
useless_op = tf.multiply(x, add_op, name='Useless')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    pow_out, useless_out = sess.run([pow_op, useless_op])
```

and it shows following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-15afa07cd8e3> in <module>
      7 useless_op = tf.multiply(x, add_op, name='Useless')
      8 
----> 9 with tf.Session() as sess:
     10     pow_out, useless_out = sess.run([pow_op, useless_op])

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: You're probably using TF 2.0 you need to downgrade to TF 1.x

Answer (score 0):

I saw this on github :

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```

or this :

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18538

does it work for you?